# Windows Phone - equal column width

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, binding, width

I have the same problem as discripted in this question:

[Creating a table with Silverlight for Windows Phone 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4562104/creating-a-table-with-silverlight-for-windows-phone-7?s=ecffcb25-41df-4fd2-bc3a-5da266cfc832)

afaik there is no SharedSizeGroup in Silverlight for Windows Phone! 
Is there an other solution?

Comment: The chosen answer mentions some workarounds. Did you look at any of them?