# ListBox TextBlock item alignment in Grid column Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, listbox, grid, textblock

I have problem with HorizontalAlignment of TextBlock in ListBox ItemTemplate. This is part of my code:

```
<ListBox x:Name="mealList" ItemsSource="{Binding Meals}" >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="10" Grid.Column="0"  TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSmallStyle}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Price}"  Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSmallStyle}"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

In App I have this list of things:

[Actual state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlIu6.png)

But I want, that right column with "xx,- Kč" has HorizontalAlignment="Right". Every item in this column should be on the righ side of screen and below previous item. Second column in second row should be below second column in first row. Do you understand?

Can you help me? I can post more of code.

Comment: I think the problem is within the column definitions. The `*` value uses the available space, but the problem are the line breaks in your text. The width of the first column is the maximum length of a text line. If you draw the borders of the textblocks it may be clear.

Comment: The problem is that you have a new grid for each listItem. Try using percentage values for the column widths, like "8*" and "2*".

Comment: I try use percentage values, but I didn´t help. Have someone another tip??

Comment: Look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/838828/how-to-get-a-listbox-itemtemplate-to-stretch-horizontally-the-full-width-of-the

Comment: to late reply, but this worked for me:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6782452/make-grid-align-properly

Comment: It's a common mistake, @Pyush has right. You have to add the style `<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle><Style TargetType="ListBoxItem"><Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter></Style></ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>` above <ListBox.ItemTemplate>