# Androids RelativeLayout for Windows Phone

Tags: layout, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm currently trying to design a table for contact information including a column for icons like telephone, email or similar symbols and I want to align them with the text from the next column

```
icon | Telephone:
     | +1212354567
icon | Email:
     | x@y.com
```

Is there any Layout which can be compared in functionality to [Androids RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html)? I tried to work with the Grid Layout but this seems to be error prone and not exact enough. I don't want to divide my layout into columns and rows, instead I want to describe their position as it is used in RelativeLayout (toLeft, toRight, AlignParentBottom etc.).

The StackPanel can be compared to the LinearLayout, which I want to avoid as it is not suitable for my current design.

Is there any comparison between Windows Phone and Android Layouts on which I can orientate? [This one](http://windowsphone.interoperabilitybridges.com/articles/android-to-wp7-chapter-2-user-interface-guidelines) is incomplete and does not give advise for the RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you said you did not want to use a Grid but I feel that you have to in this case.

I would structure it with both a grid and stack panels though.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!-- Image for first row item -->
    <Image Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Source="icon-url" />
    <!-- Container for the details of the first row item -->
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0">
        <TextBlock Text="Telephone:" />
        <TextBlock Text="+1212354567" />
    </StackPanel>

    <!-- Image for second row item -->
    <Image Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Source="icon-url" />
    <!-- Container for the details of the second row item -->
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
        <TextBlock Text="Email:" />
        <TextBlock Text="x@y.com" />
    </StackPanel>

    <!-- Just add rows to the grid to continue the list -->
</Grid>
```

Comment: Yes that would be my last hope for now. I'm used to avoid nested layouts from Android, therefore my hope is that there is something similar to the RelativeLayout I've used to know and like :) That way I could use only one StackPanel and would not have to add for every point a new StackPanel.

Comment: this is not android. StackPanel and Grid are your very best friends in XAML. Usually you'll be using an ItemsControl with a DataTemplate, so you don't have to "add for every point a new StackPanel" (the framework will do that for you)

Comment: I'm still looking into data bindings. I thought it was only applicable to LongListSelector. Can I combine the Grid or StackPanel with the same functionality?

Answer (score 1):

There is no panel that compares, but someone that was adventurous could create one. There are many articles on how to do this, but here's one for reference. http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-creating-a-custom-panel-control

That said, there's no reason not to use Grid for what you're trying to do. It's not "error prone" or "not exact enough". SharedSizeGroup should become your friend here, though.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The SharedSizeGroup looks promising. If I want to link a cell to another, I just need to add the desired parameter to this group and it will orientate on the first one?

Comment: SharedSizeGroup allows a column or row from one or more grids to share the same size. For example, if you create a template for ListItems that uses a grid, you're likely to want the columns in that grid to have the same width in every list item. http://bengribaudo.com/blog/2011/05/21/1228/wpf-separate-grids-auto-sized-columnsrows-with-synchronized-dimensions

Comment: Thanks for the link. However, SharedSizeGroup is only available to WPF on Desktops. I was looking specifically for a Windows Phone solution as the tags indicate.

Comment: Ahh... yes, I have to apologize. I'm a WPF developer that's fairly new to Silverlight/Phone, and this was one place I didn't realize there was a difference. Here's an SO post with some workarounds: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4562104/creating-a-table-with-silverlight-for-windows-phone-7. It would also be possible to "fix" this with your own panel, but again, that's non-trivial and that point you might want to create a RelativeLayoutPanel.